# Is it possible to merge developer identity with identity from external provider?

Tags: amazon-cognito

In our application with use both Facebook and our own developer authentication provider. At first glance linking and merging concepts seem pretty straightforward but it is surprisingly tricky to figure out the answer to my question. Docs say explicitly that it is possible to merge two developer identities but this is not what I want.

What should be a sequence of calls and what params should I pass there in order to get identities from FB and developer identity merged? I am not even sure if this a merge or link in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to link developer authenticated identities with Facebook. The high level steps could look like these

1. User authenticates against your backend
2. On successful authentication, you update the logins map in your application with your developer provider name and user identifier(username) and call refresh on credentials provider.
3. This should invoke a call to your backend from your application, passing the current identityId and logins map. You then call GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdenity with that data from your backend http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.htmls
4. When the user signs in with Facebook, you add the Facebook token in existing logins map and call refresh on credentials provider. This should now invoke the Step 3, but your backend will receive the logins map with two keys 1. developer provider name : user Identifier and 2. 'graph.facebook.com' : facebook token. Now when you invoke GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdenity, you should set logins map with both the keys and it will link the identity.

For more details on implementation, please refer to this documentation and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html and see 'Supporting transition between providers'

Comment: Thanks, but could you please provide sample code? So I can clear your point.